# Why is angularJs route and animate skipping my second redirect?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, animation, angular-routing

New to angular and trying out route & animate to handle my page transitions.  Followed [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/animating-angularjs-apps-ngview) extremely helpful guide on getting it all set up.

My issues are as such:

When I tried to link back to the landing page (home.html in the example above) it wasn't working and I found that instead of using href="#" if I used href="#/" it worked.  Same goes for linking between pages for example navigation between two second level pages.

I got it working like that but I have two issues.  When on a second level page the animation between that page and another second level page gets cut off the first time.  Every other time it works fine.

Also, adding location provider to enable html5 redirect seems to break my code.

What am I overlooking here?

Tried making a plunkr and failed.  [Here's the dev site.](http://releaftherapeutics.com/adigitalus)  If you click the first tile and then "two" you can see the animate being skipped.

and some snippets

```js
app.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
                                                            //ADD HTML5 REDIRECTING BREAKS SITE IN LOCALHOST AND REMOTE
        // home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'landing.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })

        // about page
        .when('/test', {
            templateUrl: 'test.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })

        // contact page
        .when('/two', {
            templateUrl: 'two.html',
            controller: 'contactController'
        });

});


// home page controller
app.controller('homeController', function($scope) {
    $scope.pageClass = 'page-landing';
});

// page one controller
app.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.pageClass = 'page-test';
});

// page two controller
app.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.pageClass = 'page-two';
});
```

&

```html
<!-- test doc -->
<div style="background-color: #b5b5b5;">Hello World!
    <a href="#/">bring me home</a>
    <a href="#two/">two</a>
</div>
```

using angular 1.3.15 btw.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When on a second level page the animation between that page and another second level page gets cut off the first time. Every other time it works fine.

It sounds like this is a networking/caching issue. Someone in the comments section of that article had a similar issue and the author's answer was:

> I think that the request to get the page probably took too long. So the request goes out and then the animation has already run its course so it doesn't show.
>
> There's probably a few ways you could fix this. Only activate animations after receiving a successful page or speeding up your server so that everything works quickly. I'll have to look into it further.

Comment: Can confirm it is likely a caching issue; issue is not reproduced when browsing in a private window.  

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Yup no problem, if this seems like the solution I'd really appreciate it if you select it as the "selected answer" :)